# Query result to array, then access in external javascript file

Tags: php, javascript

First I want to thank you guys here, because your posts have gotten me as close as I have been in the past week or so to resolve this; but I need help to finish this.  I will admit, this process is still not clear in my mind and I am also exhausted to please bear with me

The script below has gotten me so close
What I need to accomplish:  I need to grab some data from my db, stick it into an array and then access/use the
values in that array in my external javascript file.  I'll be using on the onload event.

```
<s c r i pt language="javascript1.2">
var arr = new array(<?php 
$result = mysql_query("select account_id, display_name, id from field where account_id = $holdAcctID and required_flag = 1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count>0){
  for( $i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo $row[2],',';
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  echo $row[2],',';
}
?>);
</s c r ipt>
```

above script produces this in my view source page:

```
<s c ript language="javascript1.2">
**var arr = new array(2860,2861,2862,2863,2864,3293,3294,3296,3521,3523,);**
</s c ript>
```

**Q1** - how can i update the above array, so it holds the data from the same like the example below:
as you can see, it currently only holds, displays the id value

```
myReqField[0]
    [account_id] => 72
            [display_name] => Client Contact Name
            [id] => 2860
myReqField[1]
    [account_id] => 72
            [display_name] => Contact Phone
            [id] => 2888
myReqField[2]
        [account_id] => 72
            [display_name] => Email Address
            [id] => 2865
myReqField[3]
    [account_id] => 72
            [display_name] => Approval needed
            [id] => 2841
```

**Q2** - how easy would it be to do this and place the results into a comma separate list.  If fairly easy how would I code that and how can I access the list/value from my external javascript

**Q3** - If Q2 is not possible/easy to set up, how then do I pull the array in to javascript file.  Several have mentioned json, but the other developer doesn't want to use it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said the other developer doesn't want to use JSON but that's exactly what you're looking for.  Is there a particular reason (s)he's opposed to using it?

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    $results = mysql_query('...');
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }
?>
<script language="javascript1.2">
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: something about slowing down the process and since I am not js specific developer, I am not sure of all the ramifications.

Comment: Not sure I believe but.... Could you tell me this please, if I wanted to use json, how would I grab and display the values via my external javascript file. so,  for example, on my onLoad event, I want to display/alert() all the values in this json array that is sitting in my php page?.  And I apologize, I am sure this is easy, I am just so frustrated i can't pull all this together in my mind.

Comment: You could do a `for(i in arr) { for(prop in i) { alert(prop+': '+arr.i.prop);} }`.  I didn't test it but that should loop through all your MySQL rows and then loop through each field and output the name of the field and its value.  If you have FireBug or use Google Chrome you can just do a `console.log(arr);` and it will show you the value in the console.  You can then dig down deeper.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work.  The first alert works, but not the arr: function frmOpen_OnLoad()
{ 
alert ('Hi there');
var arr = new Array();
arr = json_encode($data);
alert(arr);

Comment: That won't work because you the `json_encode($data)` needs to be `<?php echo json_encode($data);` and also because `alert(arr);` will most likely just alert `[Object object]`.  You may be able to use `alert(arr.toString());` but I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: do I understand correctly , u r say "<?php echo json_encode($data);" should be in the onload event of my javascript page?

Comment: Unless you run an AJAX request, then yes.  That's the only way to get PHP to pass the data to your page.  As long as the onload event isn't in a javascript *file*, if it's just javascript on the page then yes.

Comment: Ok,maybe I should try this and i may need to put this in a new question.  Is there a quick easy way to write the results from the query above to just a comma separate list so between the open/close javascript tags that will appear: 72,client contact name, 2860 <br>72, contact Phone, 2888, 72, email address, 2865 [end] and so on?

Comment: You could modify the PHP in my answer inside the while loop to include `echo implode(',',$result) . '<br />';`.  It won't show up in your `<script>` tags but it doesn't matter because it would be invalid javascript anyway.